# Using forEach loop to save data in a MongoDB for elements in an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, foreach, mongoose

I'm currently using a forEach loop that iterates through an array of emails that I'm using to update and set/save the data that I'm sending over via a post request.

This is my current code:

```
app.post('/register/register', function(req, res){

var emails = ['hello@gmail.com', 'yay@gmail.com', 'cool@gmail.com']

  emails.forEach(function(element){
    User.update(
     {email: element}, {$set: {team: req.body}}
    , function(err, user){
    })
  })
  res.sendStatus(200);
})
```

This code works but I can't help but feel that it is really poorly written.  Is there something in mongoDB that will allow me to find all the documents in the array emails and I can update it all at once with the data instead of looping through each item and saving it that way?

Thank you.

Comment: the call should be a single update call, to reduce overheads. handle the array at the mongoDB side. I usually put single items into an array anyway so that the DB doesn't have to check type

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can do this:

```
app.post('/register/register', function(req, res){

var emails = ['hello@gmail.com', 'yay@gmail.com', 'cool@gmail.com']

    User.update(
     {email: {$in: emails}}, {$set: {team: req.body}}
    , function(err, user){
    })
  res.sendStatus(200);
})
```

The $in operator will match all the users with emails in your array.